# Wordpress add_filter doesn't do the job

Tags: php, wordpress, filtering

I want to add onclick="_gaq.push(..... to the nav menu by adding a filter to the theme's functions.php. Thought it would be a peace of cake, but there is no output, so something must go wrong.

This is the Wordpress core start_el function

```
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $atts = array();
    $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
    $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
    $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
    $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

    $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );

    $attributes = '';
    foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
        if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
            $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
            $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
        }
    }

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}
```

and I only want to change it into

```
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $atts = array();
    $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
    $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
    $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
    $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

    $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );

    $attributes = '';
    foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
        if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
            $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
            $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
        }
    }

    $onclick = 'onclick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'Topmenu\', \'Click\',\''.$item->attr_title.'\'])"';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .' '.$onclick.'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}
```

There are only two adjustments (at the bottom of the code)

I added this line (10th line from bottom):

```
$onclick = 'onclick="_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\', \'Topmenu\', \'Click\',\''.$item->attr_title.'\'])"';
```

And I changed the 7th line from the bottom to become:

```
$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .' '.$onclick.'>';
```

When I make these changes directly to the core file (wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php), it works. 
I have tried with **class Description_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu** and **add_filter** but both times I didn't succeed.

How to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class like this:
In your `functions.php` add

```
class Description_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu{
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        your code here....
    }
}
```

Then add it to your `wp_nav_menu` function like this:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    your existing array emelents...,
    'walker' => new Description_Walker
) );
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add it to the wp_nav_menu function.